# How can I use GPU in GPTVectorStoreIndex

Tags: openai-api, llama-index

I am working on a project where I want to train/fine-tune chatgpt like on my custom model, and for the same, I am using the below mentioned code. I am able to get the output, however, I want to use GPU for a better speed.

```
from gpt_index import (SimpleDirectoryReader, GPTListIndex,
 readers, GPTSimpleVectorIndex, LLMPredictor, PromptHelper)
from langchain import OpenAI
from types import FunctionType
from llama_index import ServiceContext, GPTVectorStoreIndex
import sys
import os
import time 
from llama_index.node_parser import SimpleNodeParser

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "key-here"  


parser = SimpleNodeParser()

'''
model_name="text-davinci-003"
'''


def construct_index(directory_path):
    max_input_size = 4096
    num_outputs = 256
    max_chunk_overlap = 20
    chunk_size_limit = 600

    llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(llm=OpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    max_tokens=num_outputs))
    # prompt_helper = PromptHelper(max_input_size, num_outputs, max_chunk_overlap,
    # chunk_size_limit=chunk_size_limit)
    
    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm_predictor=llm_predictor)

    documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(directory_path).load_data()
    nodes = parser.get_nodes_from_documents(documents)
    index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents, service_context = service_context)

    index.save_to_disk('./jsons/json-schema-gpt-3.5-turbo.json')
    return index
    

# index = construct_index("docs")
index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.load_from_disk('./jsons/json-schema-gpt-3.5-turbo.json')
conversation_history = []

while True:
    user_input = input("You: ")
    input_text = "\n".join(conversation_history + [user_input])
    start = time.time()
    response = index.query(input_text)
    response_text = response.response
    print(time.time() - start)
    # Print the response
    print("Bot:", response_text)
    if len(conversation_history) > 10:
        conversation_history.pop(0)

    # Append the current input and response to the conversation history
    conversation_history.append(user_input)
    conversation_history.append(response_text)
```

As it can be seen, I am using the method `query` to obtain results. Is there a way that I can update my method so that the computation is faster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that since, we are only making API calls to OpenAI for inferencing/decoding our indexes. We cannot speed the process up. For that we might need to use [this](https://github.com/imartinez/privateGPT) and call for open source embeddings present